# Python Pages No Rendered

Tags: python, cgi

I have created a CGIHTTPServer which works fine, problem is no matter what I do, the python pages are never rendered and the source code is always shown in the browser.

pyhttpd.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer
class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = [""]
PORT = 8080
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

cgi-bin/hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print
print '<html>'
print '<head><title>Hello</title></head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello World</h2>'
print '</body></html>'
```

http://some.ip.address:8080/cgi-bin/hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print
print '<html>'
print '<head><title>Hello</title></head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello World</h2>'
print '</body></html>'
```

I have set the permission on all files to executable, .html files render fine, even moving the file back to the root folder where the server is running makes no difference, I have tried running as root as well as another normal user, exactly the same results.

Tried googling "python pages not rendered" but have not found anything useful !

## EDIT

I have also tried running a simpler server with no overrides, but the result is identical, pything code is never rendered:

pyserv.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler
serve = HTTPServer(("",80),CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
serve.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having this issue because you have overridden `cgi_directories`.

The relevant portion of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories) reads:

"This defaults to `['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']` and describes directories to treat as containing CGI scripts."

Either place your script in the root directory, or remove the override for `cgi_directories` and place the scrips in the `/cgi-bin` directory.

Here is a good link that describes a similar simple setup line by line:
https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/

**UPDATE:**

According to a [comment](https://pointlessprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/python-cgi-tutorial-1/#comment-293) on the above page, it appears that setting `cgi_directories = [""]` results in *disabling* the cgi directory feature. Instead, set `cgi_directories = ["/"]`, which sets it to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have seen that page earlier. As in my original post, I have tried running the hello.py script in the root folder where the server is running, and the page is still rendered as code and not html.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a solution that I have verified works on my Windows machine. I hope this fixes your issue as well!

Comment: Thanks, no unfortunately it does not solve it. I also tried running a simpler version of the server with no overrides (see EDIT above) and the pages are still not rendered. Even running the hello.py in the root web folder results in the same problem.

Comment: Your edited script `pyserv.py` works on my (Windows) machine, however only when the `hello.py` script is in the `cgi-bin/` directory. Remember, when `cgi_directories` isn't set, it defaults to `['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']`.